# Bit Error Rate SIMO

Tags: signal-processing, communication

What is the general formula of  BER in SIMO systems.
My system uses BPSK and my channel is AWGN.

I found many formulas but for specific cases and no generic one!.

An example of how i can find BER with Rx=10 is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**The generic formula can be written as :**

p = 1/2 - 1/2*(1+1./power(10,SNRdB/10)).^(-1/2);

theoryBer= 0;

for k=0:1:NumOfRec-1
theoryBer = theoryBer + nchoosek(NumOfRec-1+k,k).*(1-p).^k;
  end
Note: Do not forget to specify number of receivers!.